# Remove the at symbol ( @ ) and curly bracket ( { ) from Select-Sring output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, findstr, select-string

I'm parsing filenames in Powershell, and when I use `Get-ChildItem | select name`, I get a clean output of the files:

`file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt`

But when  I try to narrow down those files with Select-String, I'm getting a weird `@` and `{` in front of my output:

`Get-ChildItem | select name | Select-String -Pattern "1"`

`@{file1.txt}`

Is there a parameter I'm missing?  If I pipe with `findstr` rather than `Select-String` it works like a charm:

`Get-ChildItem | select name | Findstr "1"`

`file1.txt`

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty name` instead of `Select-Object -Property name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **simplify and speed up your command** as follows:

```sh
@((Get-ChildItem).Name) -match '1'
```

<sup>Note: `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is needed to ensure that `-match` operates on an *array*, even if only *one* file happens to exist in the current dir.</sup>

- `(...).Name` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to extract all `Name` property values from the file-info objects returned by `Get-ChildItem`.
- `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), due to operating on an *array* of values, returns the sub-array of matching values.

---

To **make your original command work**:

```sh
Get-ChildItem | select -ExpandProperty Name | 
  Select-String -Pattern "1" | select -ExpandProperty Line
```

- `select -ExpandProperty Name` makes `select` ([`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)) return only the `Name` property *values*; by default (implied `-Property` parameter), a *custom object* that *has a `Name` property* is returned.
- `select -ExpandProperty line` similarly extracts the `Line` property value from the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs.

  - Note that in PowerShell [Core] v7+ you could omit this step by instead using `Select-String`'s (new) `-Raw` switch to request string-only output.

---

As for **what you tried**:

As stated, by not using `-ExpandProperty`, `select name` (implied `-Property` parameter) created a *custom object* (`[pscustomobject]` instance) with a `Name` property.

`Select-String` *stringifies* its input objects, if necessary, so it can perform a string search on them, which results in the representation you saw; here's a simulation:

```sh
# Stringify a custom object via an expandable string ("...")
PS> "$([pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'file1.txt' })"
@{Name=file1.txt}
```

As an aside:

- The above stringification method is essentially like calling `.ToString()` on the input objects<sup>[1]</sup>, which often results in *useless* string representations (by default, just the *type* name); a more useful and intuitive stringification would be to use PowerShell's rich output-formatting system, i.e. to use the string representation you would see *in the console*; changing `Select-String`'s behavior to do that is the subject of [this feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).

---

<sup>[1] Calling `.ToString()` directly on a `[pscustomobject]` instance is actually still *broken* as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-rc.2, due to [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163); the workaround is to call `.psobject.ToString()` or to use an expandable string, as shown above.</sup>